# Question about the MK8 Extruder

Tags: extruder

I am trying to make a 3D printer (Prusa i3 model). I was testing all steppers and all steppers are working, however the Mk8 extruder (direct drive) is not working and I don’t know why. Can someone help me?

Comment: Mk8 just says "iteration 8", but at this time that is usually shorthand for the "Makerbot MK8" Hotend/extruder design. The Prusa i3 Mk3 swapped to the previous Makerbot Mk8 for an e3D v6 hotend some years ago.

Comment: What firmware are you using?
Chances are, you've forgot to disable the rather useless "cold extrusion prevention" if you're using Marlin.

Comment: Usually, the extruder movement is protected to only move when the hot end is above a certain temperature (typically 170 °C). Please update the question by [edit] to explain what you exactly did, as it stands now,the question is nominated for closure unless more information is added.

Answer (score 0):

It’s either because you haven’t connected it properly or you have not  mounted it the correct way. This could lead to the damaging of the part and failure to work again.

Check your connections with the stepper motors and hotend power wires. Make sure the connectors are in fine condition and cords are not frayed. Ensure all power is completely off and mains cable is unplugged.